# Will using Teamviewer reveal my IP?

Tags: ip, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I will be accessing a computer in a different state via Teamviewer. The sites I work on have very high security measures in place. Is there any way possible that my actual IP address can be revealed in addition to that of the computer I'll be dialing into?

Comment: revealed to whom?

Comment: I will be accessing the computer via team viewer. I don't understand the comment about firewall logs showing the public IP address. Do you mean the IP address of the computer I'm accessing?

Comment: @Cowthulhu not with teamviewer

Comment: @james to whom will the IP be revealed? Who do you not want to know that you connected with a particular machine to another particular machine?

Answer (score 1):

The IP you connect from will be available to the computer you access.  The sites you access in a web browser from that computer will only see a connection from that computer, and will not be able to determine the IP you used to connect from on Teamviewer.  If you run any applications outside the web browser, it would be possible for them to detect the incoming connection, but only if they are specifically looking for it.